# Does pytorch provide function like flow_from_dataframe in tensorflow? [pytorch]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch

when in Tensorflow+keras, we may read images according to dataframe with `flow_from_dataframe`, so we don't have to generate all the image before training and save lot of time.

```
flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe, directory=None, x_col='filename', y_col='class',
    weight_col=None, target_size=(256, 256), color_mode='rgb',
    classes=None, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, shuffle=True,
    seed=None, save_to_dir=None, save_prefix='',
    save_format='png', subset=None, interpolation='nearest',
    validate_filenames=True, **kwargs
)
```

[reference for flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe)

I am wondering if `pytorch` has same functionality?

Just can't find it, please advise.

Comment: No, you need to create a custom dataset class.